# Excel VBA: Initialise public module-level variables when file is opened?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a whole bunch of dates in three columns which are used by several macros. Currently each macro that uses these dates has to:

1. Declare the range
2. Have a for-loop through the range to get the date-cell and
3. Read the value of the cell into a variable of type date

This also includes checking the cell isn't empty, checking the date is valid.

Instead of this, I would like to have a macro that reads these dates into (VBA) arrays, which persist as long as the file is opened. I would also like to have this macro run when the file is opened, so that the dates are guaranteed to be initialised when any macro that uses them is run.

Any way to do these things?

Comment: Why haven't you ever accepted an answer to any of your 11 questions?

Comment: @swiftslide -- nice! You've got a name and have accepted some answers. I think you'll get a lot more out of stackoverflow now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your code in the Workbook_Open() event.

1. Alt-F11 to bring up the VBA Editor
2. Double-click the "ThisWorkbook" in the Project Explorer.

You'll see two drop-downs at the top of the code window. Pick "Workbook" from the first one and "Open" from the second to have a stub for your code created.